# Accessing JAVAMAIL with out password

Tags: automation, jakarta-mail, pop3

I am not able to access java mail when no password is given.
However when I give the correct userid and password I am able to access java mail.

Below is my code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
   properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
   properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
   properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");
      store.connect(host, user, password);
```

Comment: The server has being configured so a user/password pair is essential.

Comment: Why do you think anyone should be able to read your email without a password?  If your server will let you configure your account to have no password, you can certainly use JavaMail to access it.

Comment: Thx for the reply. The administration  has created  a share mailbox in the outlook which do not require the password. This mailboxes can be shared by different members among the team. This mailbox is seen locally by all the team members in their local outlook.  How ever I have seen in java mail there is a configuration setting for SMPT server  where passwords configuration is not required.